# Old users on my website cant access it anymore after i changed server

Tags: web, linode

Okey so my domain: lbslan.com was hosted on netlify before but now i have my own server. The domain is hosted at hostgator. Users that have used the website before i tranfered it can't access it anymore without clearing their browser cache or changing browser but i cant ask 100+ users change browser or clear cache.

I've tried to contact hostgators support about this issue but not gotten a real answer they just say that i and all the users have to clear their cache or change browsers.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).